# C# XSLT transform adding &#xA; and &#xD; to the output

Tags: c#, xslt, whitespace

I have an XSLT transform issue:

```
style="width:{Data/PercentSpaceUsed}%;"
```

And the value of Data/PercentSpaceUsed is integer 3.

And it outputs:

```
style="width:&#xD;&#xA;     3&#xD;&#xA; %;"
```

instead of what I expected:

```
style="width:3%;"
```

Here's the code that does the transform: `xslt_xslt` is the transform xml, `sw.ToString()` contains the `&#xD;` and `&#xA;` which I did not expect.

```
var xslTransObj = new XslCompiledTransform();
var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xslt_xslt));
xslTransObj.Load(reader);
var sw = new StringWriter();
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
xslTransObj.Transform(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xslt_data)), writer);

ResultLiteral.Text = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi,
i had spaces in my XML like Robin said. I solved the issue by simply removing the spaces.

Comment: @Patrick this is a comment.  This is what comments are for.  You cannot comment until you have earned 50 rep.  However, if you insist on jamming a gigantic signature with a link to your blog in every question or answer you make, you're never going to get 50 rep.  Best way to promote yourself is to update your profile and provide good quality answers.  Also, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `&#xD;&#xA;` are carriage returns and line feeds either within your XML or your XSLT. Make sure the xml is like

```
<Value>3</Value>
```

Rather than

```
<Value>
    3
</Value>
```

I believe there is a way to stop whitespace being used within your transformation although I don`t know it off the top of my head.

Comment: actually it is like: style="width:{Data/PercentSpaceUsed}%;"

Comment: But the data file had carriage returns  :-(

Answer (score 11):

You're getting whitespace from the source document. Use

```
style="width:{normalize-space(Data/PercentSpaceUsed)}%;"
```

to strip out the whitespace. The other option in your case would be to use

```
style="width:{number(Data/PercentSpaceUsed)}%;"
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "\t";
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlpath, settings);
```

for input whitespace to be preserved on output for attribute values.

*note: with above settings, tabs are used for indentation*