# Remove &#xA; from String in .net

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string with `&#xA` in it the regex:

- `string value = Regex.Replace(textNode.Value, @"\s+", " ");`
- `value = value.Replace("&#xA;", "");`
- `value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\&#xA", "");`
- `value  = value.Replace("\n", "");`

didn't remove it.

How do I go about removing `&#xA`?

Note: It did function as a newline when added to a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not necessary for simple string manipulation in .Net.  System.String has a Replace method.

VB

```
myString = myString.Replace("&#xA", "")
```

C#

```
myString = myString.Replace("&#xA", "");
```

However, is &#xA  is not an actual string, but a byte, (The way 1 is a number, but "1" is a string) the code would be different.  But as the question was asked, the above would be the answer.

**Edit - added after your comment**

Based on the fact that your code sample contained "textNode.Value" I'm gussing you're parsing XML.  If so, your question has already been asked and answered here:

[C# XSLT transform adding &#xA; and &#xD; to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848841/c-xslt-transform-adding-xa-and-xd-to-the-output)

Comment: While this looks straight forward, it didn't work,  Still has &#xA; in string!

Comment: This &#xA shows up in VS's Text Visualiser, but not the XML Visualiser

Answer (score 1):

&#xA is a new line character, if I recall correctly.  If David Stratton's edited answer didn't do it for you, try this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the ampersand in your regex

```
string s = "hello &#xA there";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"\&#xA", ""));
//or more simply:
Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("&#xA", ""));
```

Comment: &#xA; is only visable via VS's Text, XML or HTML variable view, in Text mode, in XML is not shown!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Regex.Replace(xml, @"&#xa;", "\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);